# When to use a propety or method on Interfaces for Value types

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

What are the Pro's Con's on defining value types as either Methods or Properties on Interfaces

i.e

Are the only issues with threaded apps or are these pretty much interchangable ?

```
 public interface IFileSearch
    {
        int FilesNum();
        int FilesNum { get; set; }

        bool HasFinsihed { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: What issues with threaded apps are your referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you wouldn't want it defined as a method is if the implementor needs the value as a property, for example to send to a web service.

In addition, of course, if the concept you are defining through the interface needs to be both readable and updateable then a property is usually a better solution than two methods (one for setting and one for getting).

If the data is not to be updated, I often vacillate on whether to provide a method or a readonly property, but assuming no additional parameters are required and the concept being exposed is truly a piece of data as opposed to an action, I usually end up on the side of providing a property for databinding, reflection, and serialization purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Methods are not bindable, properties are.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much interchangeable. The advantage of properties is that you can do ++ or --.

i.e.

```
class Data
{
  private int var;

  public Data( int v ) { var = v; }

  public int Var
  {  
    get { return var; }
    set { var = value; }
  }

  Main( )
  {
    Data d = new Data( 10 );
    d.Var++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's dogmatic. But I think the interface used to define a group action and the property means some data, so add a property into interface looks make user puzzled.
If your interface need to define a visitor of some data and its action, I suggest you use the method not property.